# In "Being John Malkovich" is there any special significance to the numbers 7 and 1/2, or 44?

Tags: being-john-malkovich

In the movie, LesterCorp occupies floor 7 and 1/2 of the Martin Flemmer building.  According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120601/trivia), Craig discovers this at the 7 and 1/2 minute mark of the movie.  This could be a coincidence, but it could also be deliberate.

The number 44 also has some significance in the movie, as this is the age the "host" must reach before they become "ripe for occupation".

Are there any further significance to these numbers, or other references within the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference to 7 1/2 seems to be an homage to Fellini's film "8 1/2" which also deals with a similar concept (e.g. going inside the mind of a genius and seeing its inner workings) albeit in a very different fashion. The number 44 was probably chosen to reflect Charlie Kaufmann's age which was 42 at the time of filming.

What's also quite interesting is that according to Malkovich the script wasn't written specially for him, nor did the Director know that he'd be available at the time of shooting. It just happened to be the first name that popped into Charlie Kaufmann's mind when he was putting together the screenplay, [as can be read](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Rws44nfh2C4C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=malkovich+%2244th+birthday%22&source=bl&ots=GM30lGG5GZ&sig=P81tJaA4x-yBgsklvOpESDz7A5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ooC8UvTRNdSP7AbO8oGwBw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=malkovich%20%2244th%20birthday%22&f=false) in *Charlie Kaufman: Confessions of an Original Mind* by Doreen Alexander Child.